# Ruby: How to iterate over a hash and do something different based on the number of items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a hash that looks something like this:

```
h = {
    "side1"=>["green", "Green"], 
    "side2"=>["verde", "Verde"]
}
```

However, it may only have one item in it:

```
h = { 
    "side2"=>["verde", "Verde"]
}
```

I would like to output the hash so that it looks something like this:

> User changed side1 from green to Green **and** side2 from verde to Verde

When there are two items will be separated from an "and". Otherwise it will look like this:

> User changed side2 from verde to Verde

This is all happening in my rails view script. How can I write the code to be able to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
h = {
    "side1"=>["green", "Green"], 
    "side2"=>["verde", "Verde"]
}
h.map { |k,v| "#{k} from #{v[0]} to #{v[1]}" }.join(' and ')
# "side1 from green to Green and side2 from verde to Verde"

h = { 
    "side2"=>["verde", "Verde"]
}
h.map { |k,v| "#{k} from #{v[0]} to #{v[1]}" }.join(' and ')
# side2 from verde to Verde"
```

So, in an ERB view:

```
User changed <%= h.map { |k,v| "#{k} from #{v[0]} to #{v[1]}" }.join(' and ') %>.
```

If you were doing this sort of thing a lot then you might want to build a helper for it.

You could also use [`to_sentence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence) since you're in Rails:

```
User changed <%= h.map { |k,v| "#{k} from #{v[0]} to #{v[1]}" }.to_sentence %>.
```

The `to_sentence` approach also scales up to more than two elements better. So, if you also had `"side3"=>["pancakes", "Pancakes"]`, then you'd get:

```
User changed side1 from green to Green, side2 from verde to Verde, and side3 from pancakes  to Pancakes.
```

Comment: +1 for `to_sentence`, didn't knew anything like that also exists. Rails has everything you will ever need :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
hash = {
    "side1"=>["green", "Green"], 
    "side2"=>["verde", "Verde"]
}

result = hash.map do |key,value|
  "#{key} from #{value.first} to #{value.last}"
end

puts "User changed #{result.to_sentence}"
```

The output is going to be :

```
User changed side1 from green to Green and side2 from verde to Verde
```

While if you added one item only:

```
User changed side1 from green to Green
```